PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function startCMSSession()
После переноса сайта на другой хостинг , хочу запустить скрипт через консоль , но получаю ошибку
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function startCMSSession() in /var/www/www-root/data/www/my_site/index.php:104.
До переноса всё работало корректно , версия evolution 1.4.11 , php 7.4.
Как устранить данную ошибку ?
